# how to store the value of each iteration

Tags: matlab

My code is like below:

I have actually two Questions regarding my code:

1:From this code i want to find the value of D.Even I get the value of "D" but every time current "D" add up with previous "D". Like  get

```
D(1,:)=30 30 30 30 30
D(2,:)=60 60 60 60 60 
D(3,:)=89 89 89 90 90
```

But i want to get

```
 D(1,:)=30 30 30 30 30
 D(2,:)=30 30 30 30 30 
 D(3,:)=29 29 29 30 30
```

I know i can do this by extracting the current `D` from the previous `D` after getting the for loop but i do not want to do this.I want to do something within the `for loop.`

1. Another question is i need to run this code for `iteration=100 times` and i need to store the value of `"D"` for every trial in a cell array, because later i need to use those values of D.

Matlab experts need your help and suggestion for two questions.

Comment: `for error=0.2:0.01:0.39; 

for iteration = 1 ;` What's this supposed to do? Don't put `;` after a for loop declaration and also for `iteration = 1` only runs once...?

Comment: errors are constant....for every iteration error will not be changed.I just need to run this code for 20000 times and every iteration need to  store the value of "D".

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of the `for error=0.2:0.01:0.39;`.

Answer (score 1):

First part: after the loop do this

```
D = [D(1,:), diff(D)];
```

e.g.

```
D = [30 30 30 30 30   
     60 60 60 60 60 
     89 89 89 90 90];

[D(1,:); diff(D)]

ans =

   30   30   30   30   30
   30   30   30   30   30
   29   29   29   30   30
```

Second part: why just store it in a new matrix?

```
AllTheDs{counter} = D  %// This will be outside your current for-loop but presumably inside your new loop that counts to 20k
```

Comment: Sorry but for 2nd part i cannot understand your solution.What is the value of counter?

Comment: @user2663126 `for counter = 1:20000....` isn't that what you want? Otherwise I don't understand your second question.

Comment: @user2663126 Sorry your question is impossible to follow. If you want to know about saving `D` in loop iteration the firstly where is the loop? Secondly please deleta all the irrelevant other bits of the code.

Comment: @Dan.. may be second part of the question was not that clear. Now i edited the second part and hope you will be able to help me. i need to run this code for iteration=100 times and i need to store the value of "D" for every trial in a cell array, because later i need to use those values of D.

Comment: I think the second solution can't work for this case because the resulting value (that would be stored in the cell) already includes the sum. The first solution should be fine though.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I don't know what the question is. Either the OP just wants the same `D` that `diff` produces. Or the OP wants many such `D`s. I meant for the `AllTheDs` line to be after the `diff` line so it won't include the sum. But who knows.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was also the diff solution as proposed by @Dan. However then I started wondering whether the problem was perhaps that you just keep adding things without the intention to do so.

I see you have this as the only line where `rec2_Wopt` is updated

```
rec2_Wopt(1) = rec2_Wopt(1) + sum(RecP) ;
```

Hence it is logical that after the second loop, it will include the additions of the first loop and the second loop.

To solve this, start each loop by resetting your variables. For this variable it would be:

```
rec2_Wopt(1) = 0
```

Or

```
rec2_Wopt = zeros(1, length(N)) ;
```

Comment: @ Dennis Jaheruddin i have got what i was looking for just by adding Result = [D(1,:); diff(D)]; After that i wanted to count the number of N in each column of D. I have also done that by adding one loop. Now i want to run the whole program for 1000 times. I want each time one different D will get generated and from that D i will count the number of N from each column of D and take the average of "number of N". Like for first trial in first column of D the number of N is 52 times , in second trial the number of N is 51 times then i will take the average like (51+52)/2=result. Please suggest.

Comment: @user2663126 It seems like this is not the original question. Hence an answer would not be in place here. If you think you have run into another problem, check whether it is in scope of the site and if so please make a new question.